# Spring Boot 3.2.0 ssl bundle with reload-on-update=true searches for wrong location of keystore

Tags: spring-boot-3

The spring bundle watcher searches for the wrong location of the keystore. Where can I configure this?

Exception:

> NioEndpoint.certificate : Connector [https-jsse-nio-8443], TLS virtual
> host [*default*], certificate type [UNDEFINED] configured from
> keystore [/home/tomcat:.keystore] using alias [tomcat] with trust
> store [null]

my spring configuration is:

```
# ssl config
spring.ssl.bundle:
  jks:
    mybundle:
      reload-on-update: true
      keystore:
        location: /opt/certs/keystore.p12
        password: *****
        type: "PKCS12"
      truststore:
        location: /opt/certs/truststore.p12
        password: *****
        type: "PKCS12"
server:
  ssl:
    bundle: "mybundle"
  port: 8443
```

I expected that the Nio watcher also searches at the location in the bundle for any updates and not at the default location /home/tomcat